# Reflection properties Filter

Tags: php

I have a class with public, public static, private and private static properties and i'm trying to get only the public ones. I just can't get the filter right for some reason, i tried

```
ReflectionProperty::IS_PUBLIC & ~ReflectionProperty::IS_STATIC
```

or

```
ReflectionProperty::IS_PUBLIC & (ReflectionProperty::IS_PUBLIC | ~ReflectionProperty::IS_STATIC)
```

among other things but either i keep getting the static public or the private static ones.

Comment: Very good point. Also, `ReflectionProperty::IS_PUBLIC | ReflectionProperty::IS_STATIC` also gives both _all_ public, and _all_ static properties, so a combination, not the intersection. Not what I'd expect of a function like this. it seems examining the returned ReflectionProperties seems about the only way to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to query all publics and then filter the public statics out like this:

```
$ro = new ReflectionObject($obj);

$publics = array_filter(
    $ro->getProperties(ReflectionProperty::IS_PUBLIC), 
    function(ReflectionProperty $prop) {
        return !$prop->isStatic();
    }
);
```

Comment: my real issue was with the filter bits since i was aiming for the most elegant code, but your solution is actually better than mine (used two array merges). Thanks

Comment: @PeterM What do you mean by that?

Comment: That filters are flawed and we need to filter out manually instead of for example `IS_PUBLIC & ~IS_STATIC`

Answer (score 1):

get all publics and all statics then get intersect of it:

```
class Test{
 public static $test1 = 'test1';
 private static $test2 = 'test2';
 public $test3 = 'test3';
}
$test = new Test();
$ro = new ReflectionObject($test);
$publics = $ro->getProperties(ReflectionProperty::IS_PUBLIC);
$statics = $ro->getProperties(ReflectionProperty::IS_STATIC);
var_export(array_diff($publics, $statics));
```

returns :

```
array ( 1 => ReflectionProperty::__set_state(array( 'name' => 'test3', 'class' => 'Test', )), )
```

Comment: I think the idea was to get the publics sans the public statics.

Comment: oops. so it should be use `array_diff`.

Comment: That should work, though you're calling `getProperties()` one time too many ;-)